# Can you enter Canada on a visa in an expired passport?

Tags: passports, canada, macedonian-citizens

My nephew's Canadian visa and Passport expires on the 29th of August 2020. He has a new valid passport.

Is his visa still valid on his old passport, so he can enter in Canada on April 22 2020 and leave on May 21 2020?